# jQuery: how to get the index of an element in the selection array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I select all the A-s with jQuery, and get a total of 6 objects here. I want to get the index of the A in the array of 6 (so I can detect which A has been clicked, for example), but when I use .index() I get the index of the element relative to its parent. So for the 5th A I get the same index as for the 2nd, because te 5th is actually the second in its group within its div.item:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    console.log ( $(this).index() ); // returns "1" for the 5th A
});
```

So is there a way to get the index of the clicked element within the array of the selection, instead of within the parent in the DOM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at jquery documentation for [.index()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/understanding-index/). You could modify your code as following to get the desired result:

```
$('.container').on("click", "a", function(){
    console.log ( $("a").index($(this))); 
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the clicked element to the `index` method:

```
var $a = $('.container > .item > a').click(function() {
    console.log ( $a.index(this) ); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  $("#result").text($('a').toArray().indexOf(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```